# How to dynamically populate page property dialog AEM

Tags: aem, aem-6, aem-touch-ui

I have created a custom tab in AEM page properties. I want this Schema dialog to be populated dynamically with values from certain component dialogs. Is this possible to do? Please share some business practices

I have tried including the schema in the component markup itself but i am unable to find a to populate it on page properties dynamically.